# BLE Transmitting vs Receiving Energy Consumption

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, altbeacon

What is the difference in energy consumption for transmitting BLE beacons vs. scanning for them?  I was thinking of making an application that scans for a particular beacon and begins to transmit its own beacon once the particular beacon has been received.

Answer (score 7):

**Scanning takes much, much more energy that transmitting as a beacon** -- at least 10x if not 100x as much.

The details of **how much energy scanning takes depends on many factors**, including how many bluetooth devices are in radio range (more devices use more energy to process the transmissions), whether bluetooth hardware filters are used to save battery, and whether full scanning is cycled on and off to save battery.  There are also variances from one phone model to the next, largely based on the bluetooth chip's efficiency.

Scanning with hardware filters or conservative background cycled scanning typically uses a similar amount of battery as cell standby, meaning it is a significant but small usage of a phone's battery capacity.

**Transmission, on the other hand, uses so little battery that it is difficult to measure.**

More information on transmitter battery usage is available in my blog post [here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/12/09/battery-friendly-beacon-transmission.html)  I have also shown some measurements for scanning battery usage in one case [here.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html)

Comment: This comment is a bit out of topic. However did you see Google Hands Free Payment method? Instead of scanning BLE all the time they are using voice recognition do you think is a good idea to reduce energy consumption or it will use as much as or more than BLE scan?

Comment: Why do you think that should be? In my understanding, scanning is a mostly passive operation, just listening for advertisements. (I guess it might be sending scan requests to each device after getting the advertisement?)

Comment: Beacon packets are really small.  When you transmit them, the transmitter is only turned on for a tiny period of time for each beacon packet.  Plus, the low-energy part of Bluetooth LE means that it does not take much power to transmit one.  When you listen for them, the receiver is turned on *all the time*, and for each packet received, processing power must be expended to decode them.  It may seem passive, but a lot of work is actually going on there.

Comment: @davidgyoung A coin-powered receiver does not need to be "turned on all the time" if the transmitter (for which we assume no power limitation) is always advertising. Receiver only needs to listen for twice the advertisement time to guarantee getting one complete advertisement, so a coin-receiver strategy only requires like twice the radio time as the alternative coin-transmitter strategy (for a given long latency, say 1 minute).

Comment: @davidgyoung Also, in principle, transmit power must increase as the square of the distance between devices, but receive power does not increase.  So, there must be some large distance at which the coin-receiver strategy (i.e., being a tiny scanner) is better than the coin-transmitter strategy (i.e., being a tiny advertiser), right?

Comment: The key reason receiver power efficiency can almost never match transmitter efficiency is because you cannot predict when transmissions will happen.  So even if you cycle the receiver, you must leave the receiver powered for much longer periods than the transmitter is powered to hope to catch the transmission.  Transmissions cannot be “constant” like an analog transmission.  The advertising packets are tiny brief bursts with a fixed max output power by regulation.  And the BLE standard used by all off-the-shelf chipsets enforces relatively long delays between bursts.